# Piral CLI extension arguments format

Tags: piral

I was looking into developing a piral-cli extension and had a couple questions about the `CliPluginApi` interface:

```js
module.exports = function (cliApi) {
  cliApi.withCommand({
    name: 'dependencies-pilet',
    alias: ['deps-pilet'],
    description: 'Lists the dependencies of the current pilet.',
    arguments: [],
    flags(argv) {
      return argv
        .boolean('only-shared')
        .describe('only-shared', 'Only outputs the declared shared dependencies.')
        .default('only-shared', false)
        .string('base')
        .default('base', process.cwd())
        .describe('base', 'Sets the base directory. By default the current directory is used.');
    },
    run(args) {
      // your code here, where args.onlyShared refers to our custom argument
    },
  });
};
```

What is the distinction between `arguments` and `flags` in a `ToolCommand`? Are arguments just required positional arguments? Need the positionals be listed again?

Final question on this one - I want to get a list of positionals like an array. Whats the syntax for this? I tried `arguments: ['list[]'],` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes arguments are positional, however, they may be optional, too.

For anything in this area please check out the [documentation of Yargs](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#positional-arguments). This may be helpful.

Still you may use flags with the argv to describe these positionals, e.g.:

```js
return argv
    .positional('source', {
        type: 'string',
        describe: 'Sets the source root directory or index.html file for collecting all the information.',
        default: apps.debugPiralDefaults.entry,
    })
    // ...
```

Regarding your question with the array: To allow multiple you can use the `..` suffix for your positional name.

In your case that would have meant: `arguments: ['[list..]'],`.

In Yargs `[]` does not mean array, but rather optional. This is opposed to `<>`, which means required. For the positional description still use, e.g., `string` -> you only describe one element here, but since you specified `..` the transported data type will always be an `Array<T>`, where `T` is the single type you gave to Yargs.

Hope that helps!